# How to insert 100000 records in a schema

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using Php 5.4, mySql 5.6

I have a schema that I need to fill with 100000s entries in a single query (for testing purpose). I have some problems because the server takes too long to elaborate, so it reaches the time limit for the elaboration. Or it directly fails the call to the database, sending a message of general fatal error without any further explanation.

My question is simple: why? Are there some php parameters that have to be changed?

Moreover, is better to run a single insert more that 1000000 times or a single multi-insert query with 1000000 records?

P.S.: if I cycle 13 times a single instance which inserts 8000 records everything it's ok and it doesn't take so long...

Comment: I am not sure, why your single query fails. there are too many variables that could cause the procedure to fail, like tons of different server settings. but IMHO the approach to do it in blocks of a few thousand should be the best performance-wise and in terms of being the most practical. with this method you can try to send one block again if it fails the first time - and it's easier to localize an error.

Comment: I tried to split the query in shorter queries and run them one after the other. Not only I solved my problem, but it's much faster now. 
Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, for example:

```
<?php
$x=1;
$col1 = 1;
$col2 = 1;
$col3 = 1;
$quantity = 1000000-1; 
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES ('$col1', '$col2', '$col3') ";

while ($x <= $quantity)
{
     $col1++;
     $col2++;
     $col3++;
     $x++;
     $query .= ", ('$col1', '$col2', '$col3') ";
}
echo $query;
?>
```

Changing quantity to `100-1` generates this:

> INSERT INTO `table` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1') ,
>   ('2', '2', '2') , ('3', '3', '3') , ('4', '4', '4') , ('5', '5', '5')
>   , ('6', '6', '6') , ('7', '7', '7') , ('8', '8', '8') , ('9', '9',
>   '9') , ('10', '10', '10') , ('11', '11', '11') , ('12', '12', '12') ,
>   ('13', '13', '13') , ('14', '14', '14') , ('15', '15', '15') , ('16',
>   '16', '16') , ('17', '17', '17') , ('18', '18', '18') , ('19', '19',
>   '19') , ('20', '20', '20') , ('21', '21', '21') , ('22', '22', '22') ,
>   ('23', '23', '23') , ('24', '24', '24') , ('25', '25', '25') , ('26',
>   '26', '26') , ('27', '27', '27') , ('28', '28', '28') , ('29', '29',
>   '29') , ('30', '30', '30') , ('31', '31', '31') , ('32', '32', '32') ,
>   ('33', '33', '33') , ('34', '34', '34') , ('35', '35', '35') , ('36',
>   '36', '36') , ('37', '37', '37') , ('38', '38', '38') , ('39', '39',
>   '39') , ('40', '40', '40') , ('41', '41', '41') , ('42', '42', '42') ,
>   ('43', '43', '43') , ('44', '44', '44') , ('45', '45', '45') , ('46',
>   '46', '46') , ('47', '47', '47') , ('48', '48', '48') , ('49', '49',
>   '49') , ('50', '50', '50') , ('51', '51', '51') , ('52', '52', '52') ,
>   ('53', '53', '53') , ('54', '54', '54') , ('55', '55', '55') , ('56',
>   '56', '56') , ('57', '57', '57') , ('58', '58', '58') , ('59', '59',
>   '59') , ('60', '60', '60') , ('61', '61', '61') , ('62', '62', '62') ,
>   ('63', '63', '63') , ('64', '64', '64') , ('65', '65', '65') , ('66',
>   '66', '66') , ('67', '67', '67') , ('68', '68', '68') , ('69', '69',
>   '69') , ('70', '70', '70') , ('71', '71', '71') , ('72', '72', '72') ,
>   ('73', '73', '73') , ('74', '74', '74') , ('75', '75', '75') , ('76',
>   '76', '76') , ('77', '77', '77') , ('78', '78', '78') , ('79', '79',
>   '79') , ('80', '80', '80') , ('81', '81', '81') , ('82', '82', '82') ,
>   ('83', '83', '83') , ('84', '84', '84') , ('85', '85', '85') , ('86',
>   '86', '86') , ('87', '87', '87') , ('88', '88', '88') , ('89', '89',
>   '89') , ('90', '90', '90') , ('91', '91', '91') , ('92', '92', '92') ,
>   ('93', '93', '93') , ('94', '94', '94') , ('95', '95', '95') , ('96',
>   '96', '96') , ('97', '97', '97') , ('98', '98', '98') , ('99', '99',
>   '99') , ('100', '100', '100')

It's not adviced to do so. It's going to take a while to run and I'm not sure if it will work, you can increase the timeout for the page to make sure it runs.

But since it's for testing purposes..
You can change the values of the col variables if you want, but you can't use `$var++` on strings.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that the test takes longer than the 30 seconds or so that PHP allows before killing the process?
If so, you can set `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`.

See

- http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't the main issue, but it helped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to minimise the traffic between the application server and the SQL engine:

Start by inserting just one record, and then in a PHP loop, double the number of records in each iteration:

First record:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE mytable (txt) VALUES ('Test');
```

In a loop:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE mytable (txt)
SELECT txt FROM mytable;
```

If you execute this loop 20 times, you'll end up with 2<sup>20</sup> records, i.e. ~ 1000000

If you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id field, it will of course be filled with unique values. You can also increment another numerical field explicitly, like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE mytable (num) VALUES (1);
```

In a loop (PHP):

```
$count = 1;
foreach (range(1, 20) as $i) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE mytable (num)
            SELECT num + $count FROM mytable";
    $mysqli->query($sql);
    $count += $count; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should insert this one by one for best perfomance and for more clear statement. You should also remove any index or constrains as well as use MyISAM instead of innodb for fastest sql insert. Best is to use .sql file and console input.

Comment: one by one is obviously not the fastest - just think of the overhead of thousands of unnecessary `INSERT INTO table(field1, field2, ...` alone that need to be send to the server. and the `MySQL` server can't optimize anything - it needs to execute every single query for itself.